# How do I count all occurrences of a phrase in a text file using regular expressions?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, nlp

I am reading in multiple files from a directory and attempting to find how many times a specific phrase (in this instance "at least") occurs in each file (not just that it occurs, but how many times in each text file it occurs)  My code is as follows

```
import glob
import os

path = 'D:/Test'

k = 0

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        f = open(filename)
        data = f.read()
        data.split()
        data.lower()
        S = re.findall(r' at least ', data, re.MULTILINE)
        count = []
        if S == True:
         for S in data:
          count.append(data.count(S))
          k= k + 1
          print("'{}' match".format(filename), count)
        else:
         print("'{}' no match".format(filename))
print("Total number of matches", k)
```

At this moment I get no matches at all.  I can count whether or not there is an occurrence of the phrase but am not sure why I can't get a count of all occurrences in each text file.

Any help would be appreciated.

regards

Comment: Try printing `data` and `S`. Hint: neither is the type you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the regex entirely, the count-method of string objects is enough, much of the other code can be simplified as well.

You're also not changing data to lower case, just printing the string as lower case, note how I use `data = data.lower()` to actually change the variable.

Try this code:

```
import glob
import os

path = 'c:\script\lab\Tests'

k = 0

substring = ' at least '
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        f = open(filename)
        data = f.read()
        data = data.lower()
        S= data.count(substring)
        if S:
            k= k + 1
            print("'{}' match".format(filename), S)
        else:
            print("'{}' no match".format(filename))
print("Total number of matches", k)
```

If anything is unclear feel free to ask!

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks.  I have about 80 of these phrases which I need to process and write out to a csv file for exporting to another program.  Creating a string list of these phrases seems to throw an error, so would I be able to do this by creating a single large string instead, or maybe building a Panda which containing the phrase and a second variable for storing the total number of each phrase?

Comment: @JFDA_64 That should be doable! Probably best asked as a new question though, where you can include the current working code and go into detail on your input and desired output more. Feel free to tag me and I can take a look if noone beats me to it.

Answer (score 0):

You make multiple mistakes in your code. `data.split()` and `data.lower()` have no effect at all, since the both do not modifiy data but return a modified version. However, you don't assign the return value to anything, so it is lost.
Also, you should always close a resource (e.g. a file) when you don't need it anymore.

Also, you append every string you find using `re.search` to a list S, which you dont use for anything anymore. It would also be pointless, because it would just contain the string you are looking for x amount of time. You can just take the list that is returned by `re.search` and comupute its length. This gives you the number of times it occurs in the text. Then you just increase your counter variable `k` by that amount and move on to the next file. You can still have your print statements by simply printing the temporary `num_found` variable.

```
import re
import glob
import os

path = 'D:/Test'

k = 0

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        f = open(filename)
        text = f.read()
        f.close()
        num_found = len(re.findall(r' at least ', data, re.MULTILINE))
        k += num_found
```

Comment: You’d be much more pythonic using `with open(filename) as f:` context manager because then you don’t have to use `f.close()`. Also as you’re reading text you should open the file in ‘rt’ mode.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the context manager, I didn't want to introduce too many new concepts though. The 'rt' mode is the default mode for the open function, therefore you don't need to explicitly specifiy it.