# Writing out a list of phrases to a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, nlp, export-to-csv

Following on from an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65295940/how-do-i-count-all-occurrences-of-a-phrase-in-a-text-file-using-regular-expressi), I have written some Python code to calculate the frequency of occurrences of certain phrases (contained in the "word_list" variable with three examples listed but will have many more) in a large number of text files.  The code I've written below requires me to take each element of the list and insert it into a string for comparison to each text file.  However the current code is only writing the frequencies for the last phrase in the list rather than all of them to the relevant columns in a spreadsheet.  Is this just an indent issue, not placing the writerow in the correct position or is there a logic flaw in my code.  Also  is there any way to avoid using a list to string assignment in order to compare the phrases to those in the text files?

```
word_list = ['in the event of', 'frankly speaking', 'on the other hand']
S = {}
p = 0
k = 0

with open(file_path, 'w+', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(["Fohone-K"] + word_list)

    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
     if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        f = open(filename)
        Fohone-K = filename[8:]
        data = f.read()
        # new code section from scratch file
        l = len(word_list)
        for s in range(l):
         phrase = word_list[s]
         S = data.count((phrase))
         if S:
          #k = k + 1
          print("'{}' match".format(Fohone-K), S)
         else:
          print("'{} no match".format(Fohone-K))
          print("\n")

          # for m in word_list:
     if S >= 0:
      print([Fohone-K] + [S])
     writer.writerow([Fohone-K] + [S])
```

The output currently looks like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMReU.png)

When it needs to look like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXB05.png)

Comment: This might be a good time for you to practice your debug skills. The following two references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: How do I get this to write the output as a row instead of everything as a column?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input file, can you show what you currently get in the output, and what you would like to get?

Comment: The input is simply a series of text files in a directory each containing a large body of text.  The output should be a .csv file with the name of the file in the first column, and a count of the number of phrases in the subsequent row.  What I get is the text file name being repeated in the first column (dependant on the number of phrases in the list) and the number of phrases for each file in the second column. I've added screen shots of the actual and required output above in the original question.

Comment: Please fix your syntax errors and indentation before posting code - the code you posted won't run, even if someone had input files.

Comment: I've just ran the code on my machine and it works without throwing an error message about indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably were going for something like this:

```
import csv, glob, os

word_list = ['in the event of', 'frankly speaking', 'on the other hand']
file_path = 'out.csv'
path = '.'

with open(file_path, 'w+', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(["Fohone-K"] + word_list)

    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            with open(filename) as f:
                postfix = filename[8:]
                content = f.read()
                matches = [content.count(phrase) for phrase in word_list]
                print(f"'{filename}' {'no ' if all(n == 0 for n in matches) else ''}match")
                writer.writerow([postfix] + matches)
```

The key problem was you were writing `S` on each row, which only contained a single count. That's fixed here by writing a full set of matches.

Comment: Just tried your code on a small section of phrases and text files and it works perfectly. Will run it on a larger sample tomorrow, but thanks for your help.